# How to compare array of objects and array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to compare two arrays:

```
var objects = [{name: 'a', is: false}, {name: 'b', is: false}, {name: 'c', is: false}];
var strings = ['a', 'b'];
```

if object from objects is equal one of string from strings change field `is` to true, but I have no idea how I can do it

Comment: When asking a question, It would be always nice to a have a piece of code that you have tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

- `includes()` to check whether `name` is present in `strings`
- `map()` to get a array with new values of `is` property

```js
var objects = [{name:'a',is:false},{name:'b',is:false},{name:'c',is:false}];
var strings = ['a','b'];

let res = objects.map(x => ({...x,is:strings.includes(x.name)}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over *objects* array and use *indexOf* to check if the current object's *name* property is present in the *strings* array

```
var objects = [{name:'a',is:false},{name:'b',is:false},{name:'c',is:false}];
var strings = ['a','b'];

objects.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (strings.indexOf(obj.name)!=-1) obj.is = true;
})

console.log(objects);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22583665)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Array.From](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
   var objects = [{name: 'a', is: false}, {name: 'b', is: false}, {name: 'c', is: false}];
   var strings = ['a', 'b'];

  var result = Array.from(objects, (o)=>{  return  {...o, is:strings.includes(o['name'])}; });

   console.log(result);
```

Hope this helps you !

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the accepted answer above. Here is how you can then filter and return an array of the names that matched.

```
  var objects = [{
      name: 'a',
      is: false
    }, {
      name: 'b',
      is: false
    }, {
      name: 'c',
      is: false
    }];
    var strings = ['a', 'b'];
    
    var matchedNames = objects.map((item) => ({...item, display: strings.includes(item.name)})).filter(item => item.display == true).map(({name}) => name)
    
    console.log(matchedNames)
```